# How can I clear the address field/bar in Chrome (diggler like)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm used to [diggler](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/neo-diggler/) in Firefox, and I really miss this feature in Chrome.

Anyone knows about a plugin that creates a button near the address bar that permits with a click to clear the field?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is: <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>

Comment: Too bad that F6 in X11 selects all the text in the address bar, substituting what I had in my 'select' clipboard, thus vanifying the use case I have in clicking a button (to paste text without using slower 'cut' & 'paste' systems instead of middle mouse button).

Thanks for the answer but I really need a button to clear the field.

Comment: @mammadori What are you trying to achieve by clearing the address bar? Maybe there's another approach.